# AMD Radeon HD 7560D Driver on Ubuntu 20.0.4

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, radeon

So here's my problem. I have a spare PC running Ubuntu 20.0.4, and it uses integrated graphics. The CPU is an AMD A8-5500, and the graphics are AND Radeon HD 7560D. I have searched everywhere for an up-to-date driver, but everywhere I look is horrifyingly out-of-date. I couldn't even find the driver on AMD's website, until, after a while, I did. But it was made for Ubuntu 14.04. Everywhere I've read it says that using old software such as that on newer versions of Ubuntu is dangerous due to it being designed for outdated versions of Kernel. Would it be safe to use the driver?